# What is the name for the idiom using method chaining to build an object?

Tags: design-patterns, coding-style, code-quality, patterns-and-practices, method-chaining

I frequently use a pattern where I using [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to setup an object, similar to a `Builder` or `Prototype` pattern, but not creating new objects with each method call, instead modifying the original object.

**Example:**

```
new Menu().withItem("Eggs").withItem("Hash Browns").withStyle("Diner");
```

Just wondering if there is a name for this pattern and whether it is considered an anti-pattern, because although it can read more fluently, it can lead to long method chains.

Comment: A fluent interface is a matter of style. If you are writing an API provide alternative forms to it.

Comment: For more discussion, take a look at this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69519/c-when-to-go-fluent

Comment: @Oded It is possible to use such an API without chaining by just making each call a separate statement, or did you have another idea for an alternative?

Comment: @GarrettHall - Of course it is possible, but then you end up calling things like `menu.withStyle("")` without context. You need _two_ APIs in such a case.

Comment: @GarrettHall The point of the 'fluent interface' *is* the method chain, which is meant to be read like a sentence. In this sense, the long method chain is not considered bad. But, and here I agree with Oded, it would be best to also provide the same functionality in a more conventional syntax. That way, the developer can choose which method to use.

Comment: A great discussion on the subject can be heard on the HanselMinutes podcast at: http://www.hanselminutes.com/260/net-api-design-that-optimizes-for-programmer-joy-with-jonathan-carter

Comment: I have a theory that if a person likes fluent interfaces, that they'll like functional programming. FI is semantically very similar to FP.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Fluent Interface**

I've always heard of this method being called a '[fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)', as coined by Eric Evans (of [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) fame) and Martin Fowler (of [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) fame).

The main drawbacks are the readability (which some folks love and some hate), and the fact that it can be harder to debug in some cases because the entire chain of actions may be considered a single statement when stepping through it.

I certainly don't consider it an anti-pattern, although I've only used the technique a few times myself.

Comment: Note that the proponents are pretty insistent that a fluent interface involves much more than just method chaining, although it is often unclear what else is meant by that term.

Comment: Is it common for the entire chain to be considered a single statement? That sounds like a poorly designed debugger issue to me.

Comment: I've not come across a debugger that treats chains as a single statement, but it can still be a pain if you're only interested in one of the methods towards the end of the chain, in one particular chain.

Comment: I work in C#, and the .NET debugger lets me step into the individual methods just fine. Other languages, I'm not so sure.

Comment: @KilianFoth As noted in the question's comments, the chained methods in a fluent interface should be readable almost as a sentence.  Sometimes this means that the individual methods should have different names than is otherwise considered good practice

Comment: @ EricKing That's true, but as @vaughandroid notes, if you are interested in a method at the end, there is no way to step over one of the calls, nor set a breakpoint at the last method call so that the debugger stops right before the call you are interested in.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Yeah, definitely. I agree. That's why I listed debugging experience as one of the drawbacks to this style.

Comment: Fluent interfaces is a sneak attack on closed source... with open source you just go to the source of the method you want and place a breakpoint inside it :D

Answer (score 7):

Method chaining like that is usually called a Fluent Interface when there is some kind of flow or discoverability in the chain. Alternatively, you can think of an api like jQuery that relies heavily on method chaining as not 'fluent' because there's not the same emphasis on discoverability -- it's more for convenience.

For your example (using withx, withy) you can consider this a variant of the Builder pattern because you've got a specialized class that, given some state (method calls) knows how to return a properly configured object.

This isn't an anti-pattern if used appropriately.

Comment: What is discoverabilty? The ability to find the methods you need through the API's autocomplete?

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. How are their method chains only for convenience, not discoverability? Because there are so many ways to chain it is overwhelming even with autocomplete?

Answer (score 3):

> whether it is considered an anti-pattern,

definitely not an anti-pattern. jQuery is probably the most well used implementation of this.

> because although it can read more fluently, it can lead to long method
>   chains

Yes it can, but what is the alternative ? You can end up with almost a plain english sentence, with the api guiding you to what is available and appropriate.

Comment: ..and you get what you want in 1 line, instead of 8 - 10. Which is good if you are only writing a one liner in a terminal. Easier to recall 1 command than 10. Because it is fluent and the methods have descriptive names it is also easier to read. Sadly a lot of this in Python2 can no longer be done in Python3/Python4.